# Why is wrong code generated by Linq-to-SQL, but there's no error when compiling

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I use Linq-to-SQL which will generate classes for database tables dragged to its designer. When I drag `Product` table to designer, Visual Studio will generate like this:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Products")]
public partial class Product : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // ...
    partial void OnProductIDChanging(int value);
    partial void OnProductIDChanged();

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ProductID", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
    public int ProductID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ProductID;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._ProductID != value))
            {
                this.OnProductIDChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._ProductID = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("ProductID");
                this.OnProductIDChanged();
            }
        }
    }
     //...
}
```

`OnProductIDChanging` and `OnProductIDChanged` are not abstract methods and they are empty but why they don't give compiling-error. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? Why should the compiler trigger an error with empty methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they are partial methods.

[This article](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2007/07/28/c-3-0-partial-methods-what-why-and-how.aspx) has a very good explanation of partial methods.

Answer (score 3):

Because they're [partial methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx). From MSDN:

> One part of the class contains the signature of the method. An
>   optional implementation may be defined in the same part or another
>   part. If the implementation is not supplied, then the method and all
>   calls to the method are removed at compile time.